# Computer makes USB unplugged noise when I run the microwave/heater

Tags: circuit-breaker, power, microwave-oven

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask, but my computer, heater, and microwave are all on the same socket.  I have had times when if I run the microwave, the fuse blows.  But just curious, if I have the heater off, but run the microwave, the computer makes the "dun-duuh" noise of a usb drive being unplugged.  Is this because there is insufficient power?  Something else weird?  Would getting a UPS assist with these moments of power insufficiency?  Other solutions (obviously running another fuse to spread the load is the long term solution).

Comment: Do you have a USB device connected which has its own power supply?

Comment: Don't believe so, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A heater often uses almost all of the current capacity of a circuit. A microwave, unless it is some tiny little portable unit, will often use enough amperage on a circuit where it should be recommended to run the unit on its own dedicated circuit.

Considering the above it is playing a dangerous game to be running your computer on the same circuit as these other heavy load devices. Low power conditions going into the computer could wreak more havoc than simply making the USB device detection circuit get falsely triggered. You run direct risk of a glitched write to the hard drive / SSD causing the system to become unbootable. There is also a distinct possibility that power surges could cause the internal DRAM content to be compromised causing invalid data to be stored in files or causing running software to perform erratic actions or outright crash.

Comment: ....ugh.....  'Low power conditions going into the computer' are NOT going to "glitch writes" or "compromise DRAM contents"  A large load like a microwave may cause the line voltage available to the computer on the same circuit to drop.  In response, the computer's power supply will draw more amperate, further contributing to voltage drop.  If the voltage drops below the minimum supported by the pc's power supply, it will completely and instantly shut off.  Likewise if the amperage drawn exceeds the breaker, the breaker will cut power immediately.  It won't cause "erratic actions".

Comment: @BillyC. - Maybe not in your experience but I've had it happen. Probably the most vulnerable situation is where a heavily loaded circuit has a heater or microwave type load switching on and off.

Comment: PC's power supply outputs also do not "instantly' turn off. Even if they did any in process write to a storage device is subject to corruption. Being that the supplies do not shut down instantly as you say there is a distinct possibility of a PC's DC voltage rails can enter a lower than normal voltage level as the outputs begin to decay if the power supply has a dropout for a few AC cycles and is the able to resume operation again. Under such conditions there is no telling what may go on in the computer. So your ...ugh... is rather misplaced here.